# Making a basic multiplication table in java using loop

Tags: java, loops

Hi I am a beginner so please don't use any complicated stuff.
Here is a SS of what i mean. http://prntscr.com/1ffec0
as of now don't worry about having numbers vertically and horizontally that display what columns and row number it is.
I have my code but am totally confused on how to go about it and how to make them multiply.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x=0, y=0;
        System.out.print("Enter rows ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter columns ");
        y = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) 
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=y; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+i+j);
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like `i * j`?

Comment: Oh, great example! You might have noticed that it seems to print 'odd' values for the values. This is because you concat `i` to the String, then concat `j` to the String. So for you instance, if `i` is 1 and `j` is 2, you would get ` 12`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to give you the answer straight out, but I'm going to help you understand the problem better with some pseudocode. Assume that your x-range goes from 1 to 3, and your y-range also goes from 1 to 3.

You did correctly set up 2 loops

```
Loop x = 1 to 3
    Loop y = 1 to 3
        //Do stuff
    End innerloop
End outerloop
```

Now consider the values that will be printed at //do stuff, in pairs like (x, y):

(1, 1) , (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), and so on until (3, 3);

Obviously you want the product to be displayed, so create some variable z = x * y inside the loops

```
//Do stuff:
z = x * y
Print z + " "
```

Print z out and leave a space, because you want to print the next value without it being adjacent to the first value.

This will print all your solutions in a straight, single line. But you want it to be in a matrix obviously. The answer is to simple a simple change, taking only one line of code. After each full cycle of your inner loop, you essentially finish one row of multiplication (think about why). So the solution is that after your inner loop finishes running, right before going to the next outer loop value for x, you want to print a new line. All in all we have something like:

```
Loop x = 1 to 3
    Loop y = 1 to 3
        z = x * y
        Print z + " "
    End innerloop
    Print NewLine // "\n" is the way to do that
End outerloop
```

And you're done. You just need to put it into code, as well as accept user input instead of hard coding the range as from 1 to 3, or whatever. This is trivial and I'm sure you'll be able to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

change the i+j by i*j
btw you are printing only half of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "*" instead of "+" ?

Like this:

```
public static void print(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++) {

            System.out.print(" " + i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

And after that you might want to think about the formatting!? My advice: think about the length of the longest value (is always x*y) and "reservice" enought space for it!

Comment: ha worked but i swear i tried that earlier and it didn't work

Comment: maybe you messed up with the "+"? you need it infront of that term to concatenate the Strings " " and i*j .

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
System.out.print(" "+i+j);
```

To:

```
if ((i + j) <= 9) {
    System.out.print(i + j + "   ");
} else if ((i + j) <= 99) { 
    System.out.print(i + j + "  ");
} else 
    System.out.print(i + j + " ");
```